# Develop Flutter Plugin for QuickBlox vs Develop Native App using Native Plugins

Tags: android, ios, flutter, quickblox, flutter-plugin

I need to develop a mobile application for iOS and Android with Chat and VOIP calling functionalities. One of the tools identified by client for Chat and VOIP is QuickBlox (https://quickblox.com/).

QuickBlox provide Native Plugins for iOS and Android with APIs for Authentication, Users, AddressBoox, Chat, Video Calling, Content, Push Notifications.

I've been using Google Flutter in the past 6 months to develop apps, and I could have used Google Flutter and Google Firebase to achieve all of the client requirements except for VOIP calls.

Should I build a Flutter Plugin as a wrapper for the native plugins or should I develop Native apps with 2 code bases for iOS and Android.

I have not built Flutter Plugins previously, will I save time by going Flutter + Flutter Plugin for QuickBlox?

Thank you.

https://quickblox.com/

https://quickblox.com/developers/QuickBlox_Developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickBlox has recently released an SDK for Flutter, documentation is available [here](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/flutter-quick-start). There is also a [step-by-step guide](https://quickblox.com/blog/getting-started-with-quickblox-flutter-sdk/) on launching QuickBlox Flutter SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I came across similar requirements. We had tried to go with the flutter plugin approach using Flutter Method Channel. It acts as the bridge between the native side of the app and the flutter codebase. You can have a gist over the demo project which provides chat listing for now [Demo](https://github.com/DroidLove/flutter_app_quickbloxQ_fresh).

Comment: the source in not available  in GitHub , please check..

Comment: https://github.com/DroidLove/flutter_app_quickblox_fresh